# notify() -> all of the threads in wait set must exit

Tags: java, multithreading, jls

According to [17.2.4. Interactions of Waits, Notification, and Interruption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.4):

> Similarly, notifications cannot be lost due to interrupts. Assume that
>   a set s of threads is in the wait set of an object m, and another
>   thread performs a notify on m. Then either:
>
> a) at least one thread in s must return normally from wait, or
>
> b) all of the threads in s must exit wait by throwing
>   InterruptedException

This surprises me because I know that `notify()` only [wakes up a single thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) so *b)* couldn't happen. The *b)* option seems to me a completely non-sense because besides implying that `notify()` is behaving like `notifyAll()` it's also supposed to interrupt all waiting threads.

Q: is this paragraph wrong? If not then why not?

Answer (score 1):

> all of the threads in `s` must exit wait by throwing InterruptedException

This means all threads waiting on `s` were interrupted.

b) means that if all threads are interrupted, no thread will wake from `wait()` normally, due to being interrupted.

Comment: Thanks, but from where do you deduce that is about the situation when *all threads are interrupted*?

Comment: While I up voted your answer because has some logic I'm still not convinced is the right one. I mean we are in the context of *another thread performs a notify on m* and you claim that the same time should happen an interrupt on all threads just in order for b) to be explainable.